# buttons next to each other are linked by a random line. How do I get rid off it?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm not sure why but there is this small little line connecting these buttons together. Anyone know the css to make it go away?

```
    <div class="button">
    <a href="registerFacebook.php"> <button> Register with <br> facebook </button> </a>
    <a href="register.php"> <button> Make a new account </button> </a>
    </div> <!--end of div button-->

    .button{
text-align:center;
     }
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default underline from the link. The line you see is actually due to the space between the end of the button and the end of the link tag.

```
</button> </a>
```

Change it to:

```
<div class="button"><a href="registerFacebook.php"><button> Register with <br /> facebook </button></a>
 <a href="register.php"><button> Make a new account </button></a>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7vcFw/1)**

Comment: Hey, I just clicked on the button and now the links are not working. Any idea why?

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine, and nothing in the code would prevent that either.

Comment: Yep it was something in my code, sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by the default anchor tag property or `text-decoration: underline;`.

You can simply add a universal anchor tag style to remove it from all links like so:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or only to the ones in `.button` like so:

```
.button a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Finally a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ScL5j/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="registerFacebook.php"> <button> Register with <br> facebook </button></a>
```

I removed the space between the closing button and anchor tag

http://jsfiddle.net/4GHH4/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="registerFacebook.php"><button>Register with <br> facebook</button></a>
    <a href="register.php"><button>Make a new account</button></a>
</div> <!--end of div button-->
```

Your white spaces in your anchor tag were causing your problem. Just remove them and your problem should be solved.